# can't override nice menus css

Tags: 7, theming

I made a custom stylesheet for my nice menu in `sites/all/themes/mytheme/css/nice-menu-custom.css`

under admin -> config -> themes -> global settings I set the path for my nice menus stylesheet as stated above. 
After saving this setting, the default css from nice menus actually disapeared from the nice menu block on my site, which obviously verifies that this set up is fine.

other than that, no matter what I do, no css getting processed.

- CSS compression is turned off.
- My problem actually started with my nicemenu class selectors not working in my at that time sole stylesheet `style.css`. So figured I'm going to do overriding by the book before asking the my question. Still to no avail.
- Flushed caches over and over

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are making it sound more complicated than it actually is. (smile)

As [explained here](http://drupal.org/node/263967), you may consider simply registering  your custom stylesheet in your theme's .info file:

```
stylesheets[all][] = nice-menu-custom.css.
```

Once that is done, you have the benefit that your custom style-sheet will be loaded with all other application's css and js files,  and be optimised by Drupal (when you change your dev settings to prod settings).

You understand that you can then overide any nice menu selector in your stylesheet, as long as your stylesheet loads last it should do the trick. If you want to "delete" an unwanted style, ***do not hack*** *nice-menu.css*, add an empty matching selector selector in your style-sheet.

THen, last but not least you can confirm your custom styles are being loaded by looking through any browser's inspector applet or script viewer, or even view source. Whatever.  In dev mode (no caching, no script compression) you should see the changes without needing to drush cc on your instance.

Hope this helps, good luck

Comment: i forgot to mention that I added the `stylesheets[all][]` in my .info file. I ended up copying the entire contents of nice-menus-default.css, pasted into my custom nice-menus stylesheet and was able to take it from there. What I did before was look at my html elements in firebug and write 'from scratch' in my custom stylesheet.